# How to reduce a list of multiple items to a key value pair object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of states:

```
['CO','CA','CO','AL', ... ,'NV']
```

and I'd like to reduce to:

```
{ 'CO': 9, 'CA':17, 'AL':1, etc}
```

The value is the number of times each state occurs in the array.

what's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Where do you pull the number from?

Comment: yea, depending on what the number is for we would suggest different things

Comment: Apologies. The value is the number of occurrences of each state. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function compress2dict( raw_arr )
{ 
  var ret={}; 
  for(var i=0;i<raw_arr.length;i++)
  {
     var item=raw_arr[i];
     ret[item]|=0;
     ret[item]++;
  }
  return ret;
}

a = ['CO','BO','CO','CC','CC','CO','CC']
b = compress2dict(a)
b
{'BO':1, 'CC':3, 'CO':3}
```

Comment: I would put a comment next to the |= as it is as elegant as it is confusing at first glance (possibly second glance to someone less versed in such things).

Comment: Please don't use for..in iteration with arrays unless you account for inherited properties and other quirks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [`array_count_values`](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_count_values:308) from PHPJS. Since the PHP [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array-count-values) function does exactly what you want, it stands to reason that the JavaScript port of that function fits.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you just iterate over the array, assign the member values to object property names and the number of occurences as the value:

```
function toObj(arr) {
  var item, obj = {};

  for (var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    item = arr[i];
    obj[item]? ++obj[item] : (obj[item] = 1);
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Or if you like while loops (sometimes they're faster, sometimes not):

```
function toObj(arr) {
  var item, obj = {}, i = arr.length;

  while (i) {
    item = arr[--i];
    obj[item]? ++obj[item] : (obj[item] = 1);
  }

  return obj;
}
```